# General formula for multiplying numbers by themselves continuously, and divisibility of a column by a particular number

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have two objectives: I want to create a column of the multiples of 2 by itself without having to format each one as (assuming that I make box `A1=2`) `=A1*A1`, `=A1*A2`, `=A1*A3`, etc.  Is there a general formula I can use so that I can auto populate a bunch of entries in the column?

Next, in the next column, I would like to generate the remainder of the the box in the previous column, by a given number.  For instance, if box A4 was equal to 16, then I would like for box B4 to populate the number 1 if I enter the number 3 (maybe these columns can start in the second row, and I can use the first row to swap out the numbers I want to divide the B column by) and to populate the number 4 if I enter the number 6.  The number I enter can be at the top and I can delete and re-enter as needed.

I asked two questions here, because I figured the first was something very simple, and the second question was really my "question".

Answer (score 0):

1. Enter `2` in e.g. A1, then `=2*A1` in A2,
   select cell A2 and use the "[fill down](https://www.google.com/search?q=spreadsheet%20%22fill%20down%22)" function to populate cells below A2.
   Or more in the style you're suggesting `=$A$1*A1` in A2, to multiply with A1-content for each consecutive "fill down" cell.
2. Remainder from a division is [=MOD(A2,divisor)](https://www.google.com/search?q=spreadsheet%20mod%20function)
   where `divisor` can be either a specific / literal number or a cell reference,
   e.g. `$B$1` will use the value in B1 regardless where (to) you copy the formula.

You need to read up on basics of spreadsheets... :-) try:
https://www.google.com/search?q=spreadsheet+basics